# PRAW: How to check wether User is accepting Private Messages?

Tags: python, bots, reddit, praw

How do I check if a user is accepting Private Messages in PRAW ?

Comment: I briefly looked through the docs. I don't think that is possible. You will have to send him a message and see if that goes through. If it doesn't a [`RedditAPIException`](https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code_overview/exceptions.html?highlight=private%20message#praw.exceptions.RedditAPIException) will be thrown.

Comment: @TinNguyen Is there any way to handle the exception/error. Can I make it such that the script will still continue to run even after the error is found, because currently the entire script just stalls if such an error shows up.

Comment: You can catch the error with `try except`.